# Face recognition with Azure Face Api using Angular 7

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, azure, face-recognition

I need to develop a face recognition system in using Angular with Azure Face API. However, the documentation for Azure Face API is in C#. Could anyone help me rewrite it to typescript?

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/face/face-api-how-to-topics/howtoidentifyfacesinimage) is the guildline for face recognition in Azure Face API

```
https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect[?returnFaceId][&returnFaceLandmarks][&returnFaceAttributes]
&subscription-key=<Subscription key>

faceServiceClient = new FaceServiceClient("<Subscription Key>");

// Create an empty PersonGroup
string personGroupId = "myfriends";
await faceServiceClient.CreatePersonGroupAsync(personGroupId, "My Friends");

// Define Anna
CreatePersonResult friend1 = await faceServiceClient.CreatePersonAsync(
    // Id of the PersonGroup that the person belonged to
    personGroupId,    
    // Name of the person
    "Anna"            
);

// Directory contains image files of Anna
const string friend1ImageDir = @"D:\Pictures\MyFriends\Anna\";

foreach (string imagePath in Directory.GetFiles(friend1ImageDir, "*.jpg"))
{
    using (Stream s = File.OpenRead(imagePath))
    {
        // Detect faces in the image and add to Anna
        await faceServiceClient.AddPersonFaceAsync(
            personGroupId, friend1.PersonId, s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding the sample code and code repo path as you are a new SO member but please ensure to check the  https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/10/04/asking-better-questions/

Answer (score 2):

Here is sample code in typescript for Face recognition.

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

@Injectable()
export class FaceRecognitionService {
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  scanImage(subscriptionKey: string, base64Image: string) {
    const headers = this.getHeaders(subscriptionKey);
    const params = this.getParams();
    const blob = this.makeblob(base64Image);

    return this.httpClient.post<FaceRecognitionResponse>(
      environment.endpoint,
      blob,
      {
        params,
        headers
      }
    );
  }

  private makeblob(dataURL) {
    const BASE64_MARKER = ';base64,';
    const parts = dataURL.split(BASE64_MARKER);
    const contentType = parts[0].split(':')[1];
    const raw = window.atob(parts[1]);
    const rawLength = raw.length;
    const uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(rawLength);

    for (let i = 0; i < rawLength; ++i) {
      uInt8Array[i] = raw.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    return new Blob([uInt8Array], { type: contentType });
  }

  private getHeaders(subscriptionKey: string) {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream');
    headers = headers.set('Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key', subscriptionKey);

    return headers;
  }

  private getParams() {
    const httpParams = new HttpParams()
      .set('returnFaceId', 'true')
      .set('returnFaceLandmarks', 'false')
      .set(
        'returnFaceAttributes',
        'age,gender,headPose,smile,facialHair,glasses,emotion,hair,makeup,occlusion,accessories,blur,exposure,noise'
      );

    return httpParams;
  }
}
```

For complete code reference please refer:

https://github.com/FabianGosebrink/angular-face-recognition-api/tree/master/src/app

Hope this helps.